# How to return modified array when deleting object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array spread between 2 components using the context api.

Adding objects to the array works fine, however I seem to be having trouble returning the modified array when removing an object from the array. Essentially it doesn't remove in the UI.

Here is my onClickHandler and a link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-surf-sqgo0q?file=/src/components/Favorites/Favorites.js:337-520).

```
  const onClickHandlerDelete = (user) => {
    const itemToBeRemoved = user;
    const array = favourites.splice(
      favourites.findIndex((favourite) => favourite.id === itemToBeRemoved.id),
      1
    );
    return array;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your UI code it's hard to say if there's some other issue updating the UI on click, but your current `onClickHandlerDelete` doesn't seem to be correct.

The simplest way to remove one or more items from an array based on a condition is with `filter`:

```
const onClickHandlerDelete = (user) =>
  favourites.filter((fav) => fav.id !== user.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment - There is a sandbox here if it helps? https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-surf-sqgo0q?file=/src/components/Favorites/Favorites.js:337-520

Comment: Okay, looks like you have a few other issues not related to this function. Your mapping has duplicate keys, you have extraneous fragments, and your `onClickHandlerDelete` isn't actually doing anything to the users in Context (`setUsers`). Each of those are separate issues and there are several good answers on StackOverflow about fixing them :)

Comment: Yep you are right. Your answer does infact delete from the array. There are a few other issues to solve.

Comment: What do you mean by your mapping has duplicate keys?

Comment: Just an error I saw in the console, I didn't go hunting for where it was occurring. I'm not sure if that mock API has users with duplicate `id`s or if it was somewhere in your code, but it's worth hunting down. The extra Fragments aren't a big deal, but there's no point in wrapping single child elements in a Fragment. And for the Context issue, looks like the top results on SO for "delete from react context" have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short snippet that should help to demonstrate the actual filtering function:

```js
const arr=[{id:4,name:"Fred"},{id:5,name:"Harry"},{id:6,name:"Herminony"}], user={id:5, name:"Kate"};

const remusr = (u) => arr.filter(e=>e.id!=u.id);

console.log(remusr(user));
```

Comment: Doesn't work as seen in this sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-surf-sqgo0q?file=/src/components/Favorites/Favorites.js:337-520